# Can I add a key to the system keyboard in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to add a custom key to the iOS system keyboard without requiring a jailbreak.  For example, when I go into any app, I want my custom key to show up and then have it launch a view from my app.

I've seen tons of examples that do things like this from a custom UITextView, but nothing that modifies the keyboard for all apps.

Comment: It would be nice wouldn't it...

Comment: It would be awful, wouldn't it. Just imagine every app adding their own key to the keyboard…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Apple has iOS pretty locked down. Your app is pretty much in its own sandbox with a few outlets to the rest of the system.

You also can't create a custom keyboard like Android.

Comment: I down-voted you because your answer seemed, to me, to be more political than technical. The other answers actually address the substance of the question, instead of personal feelings about iOS and Android.

Comment: @AlexReynolds - well apple does make iOS very political.

Comment: So does Google. They lock down their OS from competitors. So what? It doesn't have anything to do with answering the question.

Comment: What's stopping you from making a custom keyboard? Sure there isn't a nice interface for it like there is in Android, but I don't see how it's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can't but how about adding a `UIToolBar` on top of your keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the system keyboard.